# Error loading PHP OCI8 extension

Tags: php, oracle, pecl, oracle-call-interface

I used PECL to install the OCI8 extension on Mac OS X 10.7.  However, PHP won't load it:

`Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/oci8.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/oci8.so, 9): Library not loaded: /ade/b/2649109290/oracle/rdbms/lib/libclntsh.dylib.11.1
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/oci8.so
  Reason: image not found in Unknown on line 0a`

Has anyone else had this experience?  Might I be missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be the solution for me.  I already had oci8.so in my extensions directory, and commenting/uncommenting from php.ini didn't make any difference.  I had to get apache to understand where to find the Oracle Instant Client.

[Oracle instantclient DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20116584/oracle-instantclient-dyld-library-path-error/20670810#20670810)

Answer (score 0):

Consider putting `oci8.so` to `/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/` manually.

Also, following the suggestion given in [this topic](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/php-warning-php-startup-unable-to-load-dynamic-library), you could try going to `/usr/local/lib/php.ini`, trying to find `extension=oci8.so` statement and commenting it out, if found.

Finally, if neither of the methods above work, check [this article](http://blog.caseylucas.com/2013/03/03/oracle-sqlplus-and-instant-client-on-mac-osx-without-dyld_library_path/).